# How to implement in-email navigation with MJML?

Tags: html, html-email, mjml

So, I'm trying to code a newsletter using the MJML framework. It's generally great, but I'm not sure how to implement navigation within the body of the email. I would assume it would be implemented using anchor tags with the href pointing to an an element ID with a hash/pound sign in it (e.g. `<a href="#someElement">MyLink</a>` and `<someElement id="#someElement">`. My preliminary issue is that MJML doesn't seem to support an ID attribute for the elements. I am aware of the mjml nav extension, but when I looked at the extension it seemed more like a layout component than a functional one. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Anchors dont work well in Outlook. The offset after clicking is sometimes higher, meaning your email might scroll part the start of article. I haven't coded MJML, but if you do want to add in anchors, you can do this after compiling your code i would say.

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty that MJML have with custom properties is that they don't know where to put them unless they are specified. So, you can't use `id` in a component unless it is specified in that component. [See Github issue](https://github.com/mjmlio/mjml/issues/200)

In the meantime, you can write directly like so:

```
<mj-text>
    <div id="someElement">And this is more text</div>
</mj-text>
```